# how to convert binary data string into image in titanium appcelerator?

Tags: android, image, binary, titanium, appcelerator

Hi I need to know how to decode a binary string into image format so that i would assign it to imageview.Here is the what i used to convert the image into binary.

```
function toBin(str){
var st,i,j,d;
var arr = [];
var len = str.length;
for (i = 1; i<=len; i++){
           //reverse so its like a stack
d = str.charCodeAt(len-i);
for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
st = d%2 == '0' ? "class='zero'" : "" 
arr.push(d%2);
d = Math.floor(d/2);
}
}
   //reverse all bits again.
return arr.reverse().join("");

}
```

I need to know how to reverse back to image from binary string.Please help.

Ali

Answer (score 4):

You can use to encode and decode in Titanium

```
Ti.Utils.base64encode();
Ti.Utils.base64decode();
```